# How to test 'Websocket Disconnected' for Twilio TaskRouter?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm currently utilizing the Twilio TaskRouter to send tasks to different workers. I am looking into ways to manually disconnect workers from the taskrouter itself to simulate whenever a websocket closes or is disconnected. Is there an easy way to do this without deleting TaskRouter objects from the Twilio dashboard?

Unfortunately, the disconnect function found here (https://twilio.github.io/twilio-taskrouter.js/Worker.html) does not work. The function does not exist in the version of Twilio (3.49.3) that I am utilizing in my app.

Comment: How are you trying to call that disconnect method? The docs you link to refer to the client-side library, but the version 3.49.3 suggests you are talking about the server-side twilio module.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to find a way to do this utilizing a client side webhook. However, I am just asking if there is a way to manually disconnect workers from the taskrouter. It doesn't necessarily need to be with the disconnect function.

Comment: The way to disconnect a worker from TaskRouter is via the disconnect function. If it's not working for you, we should find out why.